# In an ANT build.xml file, how can I iterate over the items in the ${env} variable?

Tags: windows, ant, iteration, environment, build.xml

This is in a Windows XP environment.

I'm trying to install and edit some files that have default settings. I want to update these settings use items from ${env}

Comment: Why would you want to?  More context, please.  Ant isn't a scripting language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `foreach` from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), you could iterate over `${env}` like:

```
<target name="run">
    <foreach item="String" in="${env.CLASSPATH}" delim=";" property="x">
        <echo message="${x}" />
    </foreach>
</target>
```

I was able to do this with NAnt:

```
<target name="run">
    <foreach item="String" in="${environment::get-variable('CLASSPATH')}" delim=";" property="x">
        <echo message="${x}" />
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: ant-contrib works too =]

 what about getting each ${env.*} ?

Comment: `echoproperties` may be what you're looking for.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/OptionalTasks/echoproperties.html